# Get Key and Append To Array in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object that has a value of true or false. I want to append the key/fields only if its value is true.

**selected**

```
   {
        "1": true,
        "4": true,
        "5": true
    }

console.log({ persons: [selected] })
```

**Expected Output**

```
persons: ['1', '4', '5']
```

Comment: `append the key/fields` append to whom?

Comment: Do `Object.keys()` and `.filter()` them based on their corresponding values? But please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt and https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Object.keys and filter to get only those keys who value is true

```js
const selected = {
  "1": true,
  "4": true,
  "5": true,
  '6': false
}

console.log({
  persons: Object.keys(selected).filter(item => selected[item])
})
```

Alternatively you can iterate the object and push the keys to an array where value is true

```js
const selected = {
  "1": true,
  "4": true,
  "5": true,
  '6': false
}

const selectedArray = []

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(selected)) {
  // short circuiting 
  value && selectedArray.push(key)
}
console.log({
  persons: selectedArray
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let persons = {
        "1": false,
        "4": true,
        "5": true,
        "6": true,
    }
 for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(persons)) {
 if(value === true){
console.log( `${key}::${value}` ) 
 }
 
 }
```